# Why is "public: ParentClass" required when subclassing off a parent?

Tags: c++

From my understanding, this is the only way to subclass in C++:

```
class ParentClass {
    ...
}

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
    ...
}
```

Why is the ":public" needed? Does the child class always just inherit all the public and protected variables and methods from the parent class?

I'm not sure why this couldn't have been used instead:

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass {
```

Comment: `class`'s default inheritance access is private. `struct`'s is public.

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed, although private inheritance is a code smell as it doesn't fully reflect an is-a relationship (as should inheritance).

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass
```

is equivalent to

```
class ChildClass : private ParentClass
```

and it doesn't mean `ChildClass` inherits only private members of the base class, but limits their accesiblity to the specified level. That means methods inherited the base class become private in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have `public` there, it would be the equivalent of the following:

```
class ChildClass : private ParentClass
```

This is because `class`s have `private` access by default.

Also, `private`, `protected` and `public` are call *access-specifiers*. This has nothing to do with what gets inherited, but what you are able to *access* in the derived class.

If you want to have default `public` inheritance, use a `struct` instead:

```
struct ChildClass : ParentClass
```

The above is the equivalent of `struct ChildClass : public ParentClass` because `struct`s have `public` access by default.

Answer (score 0):

C++ also allows **protected inheritance** and **private inheritance**.

Classes default to private.  Structs default to public.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have private and protected inheritance. What you have here

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass {
```

would result in private inheritance.